CI/CD pipeline process improvements
I am looking to get some suggestions on how to improve current CI/CD pipline. Here's the overview. Let's say we have a repo TheRepo. This repo has 3 branches dev, qc, and prod. We are using Azure Devops, our release process is as follow:

developer creates local branch for new code changes, lets call it new_code
developer creates PR to push changes to dev branch, code is approved and new_code is merged into dev
developer creates PR to push changes to qc branch, code is approved and dev is merged into qc
developer creates PR to push changes to prod branch, code is approved and qc is merged into prod

The problem with this is that when multiple devs are working on the same repo and they are both pushing changes, we end up possibly moving other ppls code into the other branches, so we have to always check and make sure that the other code is good to be moved. How can we have developers only move their feature branch through dev, and qc but still allow for testing in our AWS EMR dev, and qc environments. Would we need different versions of the code deployed to the clusters? any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

An option would be single branch with version control - that is called Trunk-Based Development controlled by Feature Flags, read my post here - https://worklifenotes.com/2022/11/02/on-feature-flags/

Agree with taleodor's comment, you can consider the feature flags. In the Git branching strategy document, it mentions use feature flags to manage long-running branches. You can refer this document Progressive experimentation with feature flags for more information.
If the feature flags will be too complex to implement, you can also refer this answer of a similar question. It introduces a workflow that can better handle the branches.
